# My 3 month old daughter looks away from me

Tags: newborn, social-development

Whenever I look my daughter and try to speak to her, she always looks away from me but she doesn't do that with her mother.

My wife is the one who usually take care of her since I have a full time work, leaving 5 o'clock in the morning and coming home at 8pm. Sometimes I am the one who takes care of my child, mostly when my wife is a bit tired and every weekend.

This didn't happen when she was 2 months old. Maybe this started when we transferred to a new house near my workplace.

This is our new baby and I don't know if it is normal. What should I do?

Comment: Just curious: do you sport facial hair?

Comment: No, I shave every week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very normal for babies.  They don't care who takes care of them at first, but often develop a favorite caregiver within a couple months.  Just be glad she's not screaming at you.

Just keep on taking care of her as you have been, and maybe ask mom for a few tips about how your baby prefers certain things.  A lot of times, the scale will tip the other way in a few months, when the baby starts wanting to play more, and prefers the way dad plays.

Comment: I'll second this answer!  My baby (starting at about 6 months) wants nobody but me if she is hungry/dirty/wet/tired, but any other time, it's all DADDY.  He's her play buddy, and I don't get a second look!